# need to remove contents from dynamic page

Tags: jquery, html

I need to remove $300 , any idea? prices are coming dynamically

```
<h3>
     $300.00 <br><span>$500.00</span> 
</h3>
```

this was my jQuery code , i know its wrong code

```
$('.price>h3 ').contents().remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('h3').contents(':not(span)').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/fSXMg/1/)**

**OR**

```
$('.price > h3').text(function(index, text) {
   return text.replace(/300.00/,'').replace(/\$/,'');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/xKhaq/2/)**

**OR**

```
$('.price > h3').html(function(index, text) {
   return $('span');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Jmbvx/)**

Comment: @charlietfl definitely not, you can check my demo

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the span:

```
$('h3').html(function( i, old){
    return $(old).filter('span')
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dr7CC/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  var children = $('h3').children();
  $('h3').html('');
  $('h3').append(children);
});
```